# Java SoftReference: Soft references were not collected before the occurrence of OOM

Tags: java, garbage-collection, soft-references

it's my test code

```
public class Test {

    public static SoftReference<byte[]> cache = new SoftReference<>(new byte[0]);

    public static List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            func();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            sniff();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void func() {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        cache = new SoftReference<>(bytes);
        for(;;) {
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            list.add(tmp);
        }
    }

    public static void sniff() {
        byte[] bytes = cache.get();
        if (bytes == null) {
            System.out.println("recycling data.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("object still live");
        }
    }
}
```

The program output is as follows

> object still live

I don't understand? why?
This is a sentence I found in the official documentation of Oracle:

> All soft references to softly-reachable objects are guaranteed to have been cleared before the virtual machine throws an OutOfMemoryError.

Even more strangely, if I put `byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024]; cache = new SoftReference<>(bytes);` into the for loop; like this

```
public class Test {

    public static SoftReference<byte[]> cache = new SoftReference<>(new byte[0]);

    public static List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            func();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            sniff();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void func() {
        for(;;) {
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            list.add(tmp);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            cache = new SoftReference<>(bytes);
        }
    }

    public static void sniff() {
        byte[] bytes = cache.get();
        if (bytes == null) {
            System.out.println("recycling data.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("object still live");
        }
    }
}
```

the program output is as follows:

> recycling data.

I have two question:

1. The first writing method，Why did the garbage collector not collect SoftReferences
2. Why do these two writing methods produce such a difference

I analyzed the dump file and the first way of writing really doesn't collect it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to note in the quote from the official documentation is in bold below:

> All soft references to **softly-reachable objects** are guaranteed to have been cleared before the virtual machine throws an OutOfMemoryError.

Softly-reachable objects are those that can be reached by the "root" context only through soft references or weaker ([reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability)).

In your first example you are putting your `byte[]` in a `List`; this creates a path of **strong** references to the object - that is why it is not garbage collected in the end.

In your second example, the array referenced by the `tmp` variable is added to the list and lives at least as long as the list lives. The array referenced by the `bytes` variable however is created and is strongly referenced in the scope of `func()` only. The only reference that escapes is the soft reference. So, before the `OutOfMemoryError` it is guaranteed that this softly reachable array, the last you created in the loop, will be garbage collected. The ones you created in the loop iterations before the last are already *unreachable*, because even the soft reference to them that survived the loop is overwritten in the next iteration.

You could try changing the list to be `List<SoftReference<byte[]>>`; you will find out that all of the soft references will have been cleared before the OOME.

Comment: I think I understood the first example. Garbage collector not collect the "Softly-reachable" object because it not really Softly-reachable object. Variable `bytes` have a strong references to object when occur `OutOfMemoryError`. 
I changed my code to `cache = new SoftReference<>(new byte[1024 * 1024])` and not use variable to reference the byte array.The program print ` recycling data` prove that it has been collected.
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: But I can't understand the sencond example. Variable `bytes` also have a strong reference to byte array when occur `OutOfMemroyError`.Why can it be collected

Comment: Oh! I understand in the second example. Becauser of the variable's scope！In a loop, the pointer to a variable is constantly changing. Therefore, on the surface, the array is strongly referenced and associated with the variable 'bytes'. In fact, in the next loop, the object it references will be overwritten, and the previous old object can be collected.Is this correct？